# Regex C#: Split between two delimiters

Tags: c#, regex

Given I have a sample string below:

```
"parentstring1[childstring1.childstring2.childstring3].parentstring2[childstring4.childstring5]"
```

How can I split the string above to produce an array with the values below from `'.'` character and the '[' and ']' as delimiters

```
array[0] = "parentstring1[childstring1.childstring2.childstring3]"
array[1] = "parentstring2[childstring4.childstring5]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split using this regex:

```
\.(?![^\[]*\])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM1mK0/3)

This will split on DOTs only when it is not followed by 0 or more `non-[` characters and a `]`, thus making sure to split on DOTs that are outside `[...]`.

Comment: But this also will match a dot like `"parentstring1.[childstring1` which not precede by `]`.

Comment: Please don't link to external sites without putting the c# code in this answer first.

Comment: Please don't bring cases of unmatched and escaped `[` and `]` unless until asked specifically in question.

Comment: I didn't down vote but I think OP just want split based on that special dots!

Comment: @Enigmativity SO is not a code writing service! this type of answers are good for teaching to OP!

Comment: @Enigmativity: I don't treat SO as `give-me-code` service. I have provided a regex and mentioned the split operation. Rest should be pretty easy for OP.

Comment: @Kasra - There is a big difference between showing how to technically apply regex and a question like please design me my parsing algorithm.

Comment: What is the most important thing is that StackOverflow should stand on its own. If the owners of "regex101.com" decide to shut down their site then this answer is affected.

Comment: @Enigmativity *showing how to technically apply regex* is a mundane task that you can find it in every documentation! and about the shut downing the "regex101.com" it's completely True for SO so we just have to trust to many thing like the Power, site owners, the good Lord , the governments and .... ;)

Comment: Those are all lame reasons that some link will shutdown. That way people should stop linking anything in answers because in theory any website can shutdown. Besides regex101 is just used for a demo. Actual regex and suggestion to use split with the description of how it works is very much part of the answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity: The contents here on these answers all stand on their own. There is nothing that completely relies on regex101 here.

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = "parentstring1[childstring1.childstring2.childstring3].parentstring2[childstring4.childstring5]";

string[] arr = Regex.Split(text, "(?<=\\]).");

foreach (var item in arr)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Regex like this:

```
[^\[\.]+\[[^\]]*\]
```

This means: anything except . and [, followed by anything inside [] symbols.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(source, "[^\[\.]+\[[^\]]*\]")
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/pG3qU8/1)

Comment: Please don't link to external sites without putting the c# code in this answer first.

Comment: I agree with above: "showing how to technically apply regex is a mundane task that you can find it in every documentation!"